# Storing "global" object outside of Redux store in React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a React/Redux app that needs a globally available object (a websocket lib instance).  I originally tried to store this in the Redux state tree, however, the instance is not immutable and it caused lots of problems with hot reloading during development (tons of circular reference errors that don't exist when running from compiled code).

My question is how to store/create this instance so that it is available to my Redux code and React components?  I could create it at the very top of the component tree and pass it down the tree as a prop, but that feels very "dirty" after doing everything with react-redux connect.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Redux Thunk, authored by gaeron, he who authored redux, since 2.1.0 allows you to do:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api))
)

// later
function fetchUser(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    // you can use api here
  }
}
```

This is straight from the docs, see the link below for more information:

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Answer (score 13):

@sheeldotme's answer will work well if you're using thunks.

Also keep in mind that, depending on the websocket lib you're using, you may not need the instance as a global variable. For example, with `socket.io-client`, after your initial `io(url)` call that makes the websocket connection, any subsequent calls to `io(url)` (with the same `url` argument) will return that same connection (i.e. `socket` object) from memory, without having to reconnect. It makes it easy to have an API that you can simply `import`/`require`, rather than having to pass the instance around or make it global. See the [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io(url:string,-opts:object):socket) for more info.

For example:

*socket.js*

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io(`${protocol}//${hostname}:${port}`)
export default socket
```

Now you can simply `import`/`require` your *socket.js* file to have easy access to the same socket object from anywhere.